# Adding new first argument, then applying original arguments

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am using map to map a set of functions like so:

```
function runWaterfall(consumer, fns, cb) {

    fns = fns.map(function (fn) {
        return function () {
            fn(consumer, arguments);
        }
    });

    async.waterfall(fns, cb);

}
```

so as you can see, I would like to add "consumer" as the first argument to every function fn, but I don't believe my syntax is right.

Perhaps this is better:

```
function runWaterfall(consumer, fns, cb) {

    fns = fns.map(function (fn) {
        return function () {
            fn.apply(null,[consumer, arguments]);
        }
    });

    async.waterfall(fns, cb);

}
```

I doubt either of these is correct

Comment: Do you have any errors? Or what is the output?

Comment: unfortunately this is part of a larger codebase and I haven't tested it yet :(

Answer (score 1):

Good question! You are almost there, just need to convert array-like `arguments` to array and concat it with `consumer`

```
function runWaterfall(consumer, fns, cb) {

    fns = fns.map(function (fn) {
        return function () {
           var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0);           
           fn.apply(null, [consumer].concat(args));
        }
    });

    async.waterfall(fns, cb);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Function.prototype.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) not only to set `this` context, but also to provide arguments. You were close with `apply`, but it would call the function immediately while `bind` will return a function with the argument pre-filled:

```
fns = fns.map(function (fn) {
    return fn.bind( null, consumer )
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/qmuv8com/

Comment: `Apply` will not be called immediately as it is in returning function. In your example you apply `consumer` as first argument but lose last argument.

Comment: @RubenNagoga you're right, `apply` is called from the returned function. As to the second point: it may or may not be the desired outcome, hard to tell with so little context given in the question.